# how to find complement in two lists

Tags: python, list, complement

There are two phones, phoneA and phoneB, how to how to find complement in phoneB but not in phoneA, one ex;

```
phoneA =  ["long lasting battery”, ”clear display”, ”great camera”, ”storage space”], [“clear display”, ”long lasting battery”, ”great camera”, ”warp-speed word processing”]

phoneB =  ["long lasting battery”, ”clear display”, ”great camera”, ”storage space”], [“clear display”, ”long lasting battery”, ”great camera”, ”warp-speed word processing”, “great sound”]
```

I write code like this by python:

```
d = [x for x in phoneB if x not in phoneA]
print(d)
```

**but the code is wrong**, **anyone has better idea**?

Comment: Could you please clarify what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Why do you have two lists assigned to each phone variable?

Comment: Ah I didn't see those second lists due to the line lengths :) So both `phoneA` and `phoneB` are tuples.

Comment: @bereal I don't understand, can you edit again so that it will be correct? :)

Comment: @bereal I see, what confused me was wrong apostrophe used in strings.

Comment: @mbostic I only added the indentation, so the tuples were there in the beginning.

Comment: @hangkai wang How do you want to treat the fact that there are two lists for each phone?

Comment: What do you mean by compliment? Are you after things in b that are not in a?

Comment: The problem is to input two parameters of mobile phone A and B, which can be in the form of list or array, and then find out the parameters in mobile phone B but not in mobile phone A. I wrote the above code by myself, but there is an error in the submission, I don't know where the error is. The parameters are shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the 2 lists together, then check them:

```py
d = [x for x in phoneB[0]+phoneB[1] if x not in phoneA[0]+phoneA[1]]
```

```
>>> d
['great sound']
```

---

Or if you have multiple sublists, this will also work:

```
# This joins all the elements in sublists into one large list
d = [x for x in [j for i in phoneB for j in i]
     if x not in [j for i in phoneA for j in i]]
```